# How do I visually replace an expression in VS Code with a symbol?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for Python development.
A very common expression in python is `lambda x: x` which can be a little verbose when used 40+ times in a module.

Does VS code allow for this to be replaced with a symbol? eg. replacing `lambda` with `λ`?

So code like `df.apply(lambda x: x**2)` would appear as `df.apply(λx: x**2)`

To clarify, I DONT want to modify the source code, I just want it to be displayed on my code editor using the shorthand.

Comment: The closest thing to this that I am aware of would be font ligatures, however, I do not know of any fonts with that specfic ligature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very late to the party, but I recommend using this extension: [prettify-symbols-mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.prettify-symbols-mode)

Adding following config to `settings.json` worked for me:

```
"prettifySymbolsMode.substitutions": [{
    "language": "python",
    "revealOn": "active-line",
    "substitutions": [
        { "ugly": "lambda",     "pretty": "λ", "post": "\\s*(?:\\w|_).*?\\s*:" }
    ]
}]
```